Markdown-mode: Remove secondary hash symbol in headings
In markdown mode, when you call (markdown-insert-header), the following gets outputted:
# Title #

How can I remove the secondary "#" so that the result is:
# Title

Thanks in advance

Customize markdown-asymmetric-header to t. C-h v markdown-asymmetric-header says:

Determines if atx header style will be asymmetric.
Set to a non-nil value to use asymmetric header styling, placing
header markup only at the beginning of the line. By default,
balanced markup will be inserted at the beginning and end of the
line around the header title.

